# Get a cd of Ubuntu developer version by post

Tags: development

How can i get the latest Cd of Ubuntu Developer version 14.04.3 by post?I received a Cd of older version of kubutu by post.

Answer (score 2):

There's no version of Ubuntu built specifically for developers; the download link at http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers redirects to the "regular" Desktop LTS download page;

Apparently there's no Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 DVD available for purchase; you may buy an Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 DVD instead at [Canonical's online store](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1146); however:

> The DVDs are only available in 64 bit version, if you require 32 bit you will need to download a distribution or make your own CD/DVD

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu DVDs are available from the [Ubuntu Store](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17) though there's only the regular Desktop and Server editions in 64 bit.